# Rails + Cucumber: How to test for access to a restricted resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I've just starting with cucumber while also learning rails and did a couple of scenarios to try it out. Please evaluate the below scenario, and especially tell me a better way to do the third step definition.

I'm using devise and will be customizing the user quite a bit so I'd like to confirm that the users work as expected even if I change something.

Maybe this part is ok (any input welcome).

```
Scenario: Visitor creates an account
    Given I am not authenticated
    When I do everything required to create an account
    Then I should have access to it
```

The first two steps may also be ok.

```
Given /^I am not authenticated$/ do
  visit destroy_user_session_path
end

When /^I do everything required to create an account$/ do
  email = 'asfd@asdf.com'
  name = 'asdf'
  password = 'asdf'
  visit new_user_registration_path
  fill_in 'user_email', :with => email
  fill_in 'user_name', :with => name
  fill_in 'user_password', :with => password
  fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', :with => password
  click_on('Sign up')

end
```

But the third one gets me. I was thinking to test for either 200 success in the headers or 401 unauthorized as a fundamental way of checking whether the user has access or not. But I haven't been able to find a way to do it. If I have the right idea, what is the code to do it? If I have the wrong idea, why is that so and what is the better way to do it?

```
Then /^I should have access to it$/ do
  visit edit_user_registration_path
  page.should have_selector "something that only exists on the edit registration page" #works but seems very brittle
  # my failed attempt at using rspec inside the step definition:
  # get edit_user_registration_path
  # response.headers["Status"].downcase.should == "200 success"
  #
  # another failed attempt:
  # response.should render_template(...)
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would separate what you want in two scenarios. The first: "Visitor creates an account" where I would replace the last step by one testing the message that the user should see, i.e. Then I should see "Account successfully created". The second: "User logs in" where you can test by clicking any link only accessible to logged in users. Anyway, if you are using Cucumber, RSpec, Devise, I strongly recommend you to read [Rails 3 in Action](http://www.amazon.com/Rails-3-Action-Ryan-Bigg/product-reviews/1935182277) where you will find exactly what you are looking for. There is an example where you will also learn to user Cucumber tables, and many more interesting things.

Hope that helps,

Comment: You found this through my other answer I presume? :) Thanks for answering! I have seen that style used, but it seems to be to be unnecessarily coupled to the workflow / UI. I have separate specifications for those. I guess it's not the standard, but it fits the way I think so I've been trying it. I was thinking more along [these lines](http://ruby.11.n6.nabble.com/How-do-I-include-routing-path-helpers-td3484906.html) where he included the routing tests in a place outside of specs/routing. What I hope to achieve is just testing that the behavior works independently of interface (HTML/JSON/etc).

Comment: Ah, and thanks for the book. I hadn't seen one that uses cucumber for BDD. I'm having fun working with the cucumber style. It's a good exercise to really try to divorce the implementation from the desired behavior. [Specification by Example](http://www.amazon.com/Specification-Example-Successful-Deliver-Software/dp/1617290084/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b), an excellent book, got me started on it.